# Where does PHP store submitted form values?

Tags: php, database, cookies

Where does php webform data stores? If the form does not connected to any database, where does submitted information stores? If it is stores in client's cookies, how can I process these information later?

Comment: Form data is sent to action of the form. `action='somefile.php'`

Comment: Is this Default? every php form data goes to this file? where is it loated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s not stored anywhere, the values are only available in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array when the form is submitted and it´s up to you to do something with them. The values are lost as soon as the script terminates processing.

Comment: Therefore if form data not store on Database, we will not be able to use them later?

Comment: @Geeth Yes, you need to process / store the information in a database right away.

Comment: @jeroen - It would have been worth mentioning that one can easily store these variables in a SESSION variable or other location in the filesystem for accessing later. I know that this is covered by the term "process", but I think our friend Geeth may have left with the impression that his only option was DB storage.